# Override WordPress core function

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I'm trying to find a way to override / redeclare [wp_timezone_choice](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_timezone_choice/) function in order to remove unnecessary time-zones, but I can not find any filters or hooks to be able to customize the function from the theme `functions.php` file.

For example:

```
function my_timezone_choice( $selected_zone, $locale = null ) {
   // customized code from wp-includes/functions.php 
   // function wp_timezone_choice( $selected_zone, $locale = null )
}
add_filter ('???', 'my_timezone_choice');
```

I know the function is not plugable, I spent hours searching for a solution, any help would be much appreciated.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Out of curiosity, what do you expect to achieve by removing "unnecessary timezones" exactly?

Comment: @cabrerahector sure, I have a booking plugin with calendar and time-zone picker, the problem is that time-zone picker pulls all time-zones from `wp_timezone_choice` function, and I need to "trim the zones" for US and EU only.